# Combine List with List of Tuples

Tags: python, list

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [(10, 20), (30, 40), (50, 60), (70, 80)]

>>> print(list(zip(l1, l2)))

[(1, (10, 20)), (2, (30, 40)), (3, (50, 60)), (4, (70, 80))]
```

However, I want it to be just a list of four tuples likes this:

```
[(1, 10, 20), (2, 30, 40), (3, 50, 60), (4, 70, 80)]
```

I've also tried:

```
>>> print(list(zip(l1, *l2)))

[(1, 10, 30, 50, 70), (2, 20, 40, 60, 80)]
```

So my question is:

**How can I zip a list with a list of tuples or a list of lists?**

Answer (score 8):

A more generic way to approach this problem is to consider that both the lists should be scaled up/down to the same dimension as and when required

```
>>> [(a, ) + b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
[(1, 10, 20), (2, 30, 40), (3, 50, 60), (4, 70, 80)]
```

As in your example, the second list has an extra dimension in contrast to the first list, either

1. Convert the first list to the higher dimension matching the second list
2. Reduce the dimension of the second list

In this particular case, the first approach was easier and thus was the obvious choice

Comment: That doesn't produce the desired output, though. (I would also note that `zip` only returns a `list` in Python 2).

Comment: The fixed version is nice. I didn't know `tuple` had an `__add__` equivalent to `list`'s.

Comment: You can read about `zip()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: great. But is there also a method withput the zip-function?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3,4]
>>> l2=[(10,20),(30,40),(50,60),(70,80)]
>>> [tuple([x] + list(y)) for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
[(1, 10, 20), (2, 30, 40), (3, 50, 60), (4, 70, 80)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [(10, 20), (30, 40), (50, 60), (70, 80)]
print [(a, b[0], b[1]) for a, b in list(zip(l1, l2))]
```

This works like this: `zip` creates an array that combines the elements of `l1` and `l2`

```
>>> zip (l1, l2)
[(1, (10, 20)), (2, (30, 40)), (3, (50, 60)), (4, (70, 80))]
```

`for i, j in zip(l1, l2)` will unpack the values into i and j sequentially picking up one element from each array in each loop iteration; ie, `1` and `(10, 20)` in the first iteration, `2` and `(30, 40)`in the second, etc.

You can then reshuffle the values to create the tuple you want. You can do this either with `(a, b[0], b[1])` or `(a, ) + b`. The latter approach, which Abhijit used and is probably more efficient than mine, is based on the fact that you can add tuples (eg `(1, 2) + (3, 4) + (5,)` equals `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`).

If what you want to do with the numbers isn't overly complex, you can do it at the beginning of the `for` expression instead of just creating the tuple. Maybe you can make your code more compact that way.

Comment: @Alexander, please stop with the unnecessary edits to everyone's posts.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The Zen of Python:  "Readability counts."

Comment: It was already more than readable enough, and all we did with those lines was copy and paste them. It wasn't an improvement.

Comment: Copied crap and pasted crap.  You may want to at least take the time to edit what you copy.

Comment: There was no need. If your edits had gone into the review queue, they would've been rejected as no improvement.

Comment: What is the problem with making the result more readable?  I'm not doing this for points...

Answer (score 1):

If let me do this, it will do as below:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [(10, 20), (30, 40), (50, 60), (70, 80)]

print [ (a,b[0],b[1]) for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
```

So you have to know `zip()` how to use:

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. When there are multiple arguments which are all of the same length, zip() is similar to map() with an initial argument of None. With a single sequence argument, it returns a list of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting down another way with explicit for loop, assuming len(l1) == len(l2)

```
for x in range(0,len(l1)):
    print (l1[x],l2[x][0],l2[x][1])
```